# Form submission with JavaScript - why is it not getting values from the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So my form looks like:

```
<form id="user_form">
      <p><label for="username">Username: </label>
        <input id="username" type="text"></p>
      <p><label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input id="password" type="text"></p>
      <p><label for="email">E-mail: </label>
        <input id="email" type="text"></p>
      <p><label for="first_name">First Name: </label>
        <input id="first_name" type="text"></p>
      <p><label for="last_name">Last Name: </label>
        <input id="last_name" type="text"></p>
      <p><input id="notif_submit" type="submit" value="Create"></p>
    </form>
  </div>
```

and my JavaScript is all like:

```
$("#user_form").submit(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var username = $("username").val();
  var password = $("password").val();
  var email = $("email").val();
  var first_name = $("first_name").val();
  var last_name = $("last_name").val();
  var newUser = new Parse.User();
  alert(username);
  newUser.set("username", username);
  newUser.set("password", password);
  newUser.set("email", email)
  newUser.set("first_name", first_name);
  newUser.set("last_name", last_name);
  newUser.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user) {
      alert("Success!");
    }, error: function(user, error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

but the alert I put in as a test says the username is null.  I've tried onClick="functionName" in the HTML tag, I've tried replacing "id" with "name", everything I can think of. It's gotta be something simple...

Comment: you need to add # before your id and . in jquery
(Example $("#username")).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `var username = $("#username").val();`.

You are missing the `#` identifier in your selector.

Edit: if, for some reason, you wanted to use `name` rather than the `id` you can use the selector: `$( "input[name*='username']" ).val()` instead. But using the `id` should be suitable.

Comment: @AndrewTorr No problems. If my answer helped you, please mark it as answered so your question will be cleaned up and archived.

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery you need to use `#`, this is used to target an element using the ID.

Just update your code like so

```
 var username = $("#username").val();
 var password = $("#password").val();
 var email = $("#email").val();
 var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
 var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thanks!